# AS3 - ImageSnapshot - not taking snapshot of entire component

Tags: actionscript-3

I tried to capture the screenshot of a rendered SWF file(chart) and convert it to image by using the following code. But, the output image contains only some part of the actual chart rendered. It is not capturing entire rendered chart...please help me out...Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute"
    minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
    backgroundColor="white" viewSourceURL="srcview/index.html" initialize="initApp()">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.core.IUIComponent;
        import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
        import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import mx.events.CloseEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;


        private var image:ImageSnapshot = new ImageSnapshot;
        private var dataXML:String="<chart labelDisplay='Normal' xAxisName='' yAxisName='' pyAxisName='' syAxisName='' rotateYAxisName='' caption='' subCaption='' baseFont='Regular' baseFontSize='10' baseFontColor='' decimalPrecision='' thousandSeparator=',' decimalSeparator='.' numberPrefix='' numberSuffix='' sNumberPrefix='' sNumberSuffix='' bgColor='' showBorder='1' YAxisMinValue='' YAxisMaxValue='' pyAxisMinValue='' pyAxisMaxValue='' syAxisMinValue='' syAxisMaxValue='' showLabels='1' showValues='1' showLegend='Y' legendPosition='Right'><categories><category label='Unmapped'/><category label='FY 2002 - 03'/><category label='FY 2003 - 04'/><category label='FY 2004 - 05'/><category label='FY 2005 - 06'/><category label='FY 2006 - 07'/><category label='FY 2007 - 08'/><category label='FY 2008 - 09'/><category label='FY 2009 - 10'/><category label='FY 2010 - 11'/></categories><dataset seriesName='Base Amount'><set value='-65770'/><set value='71461203'/><set value='66548822'/><set value='87063456'/><set value='261797187'/><set value='282962118'/><set value='3830823027'/><set value='16001588683'/><set value='22514728943'/><set value='23822586701'/></dataset></chart>";
          private function initApp():void
          {
            chart_1.source="MSCombi2D.swf?chartWidth=100&chartHeight=100&registerWithJS=1&dataXML="+dataXML;
          }
        private function takeSnapshot(source:IBitmapDrawable):void {
           // var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(source);
           // var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
           // var str:String = imageByteArray.
           // swfLoader.load(imageByteArray);
            var imageBitmapData:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(source);
            swfLoader.source = new Bitmap(imageBitmapData);


            // take a screen capture
          //  image = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(source, 72, new PNGEncoder(), false);
           //   var fileSave:FileReference = new FileReference();
           //       fileSave.save(image.data, "saveImage.png");
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>



<mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
    <mx:Button label="Take snapshot of DataGrid"
            click="takeSnapshot(chart_1);" />
</mx:ApplicationControlBar>

<mx:HBox>
   <mx:SWFLoader id="chart_1" /> 

    <mx:SWFLoader id="swfLoader">
        <mx:filters>
            <mx:DropShadowFilter />
        </mx:filters>
    </mx:SWFLoader>
</mx:HBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...i changed the code for the function "takeSnapshot" as follows:

```
   private function takeSnapshot(source:IBitmapDrawable):void 
        {                          
            var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( 1350, 700 );
            bitmapData.draw( IBitmapDrawable( chart_1 ));
            var swfBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap( bitmapData );            
            var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100); 
            var ba:ByteArray  = jpg.encode(swfBitmap.bitmapData); 
            var fileSave:FileReference = new FileReference();
            fileSave.save(ba, "saveImage.jpg");
        }
```